# Haskell - Binary Search Tree

Tags: haskell, binary-search-tree

Being a beginner in Haskell I am currently trying to get my head around BST. Currently I am trying to perform a fold on a tree inorder.

This is what I got so far, but it produces an error.

```
inorder' :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> BinaryTree a -> b
inorder' _ a myTree = a
inorder' fun a (Node left root right) = inorder' fun (fun root (inorder' fun a left)) right
```

I am really dumbfounded now because I worked for quite some time now to figure out what exactly the problem is but I simply do not seem to come up with a solution.

Comment: What error does it produce?

Comment: Furthermore please include the definition of `BinaryTree a`.

Answer (score 3):

**Inorder** means that you (1) first process the left subtree, (2) then process the node itself, and (3) finally process the right subtree.

## Leaves without values

Based on your function, the definition of `BinaryTree a`, is probably:

```
data BinaryTree a = Leaf | Node (BinaryTree a) a (BinaryTree a)
```

So that means that there are two cases: in case of a leaf, there is no data, so we simply return the given value:

```
inorder' _ a Leaf = a -- with an uppercase, otherwise it does match all
```

And for the `Node` case, we above already stated how that works:

```
inorder' f a (Node left val right) = inorder' f c right
    where b = inorder' f a left
          c = f b val
```

Or in full:

```
inorder' :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> BinaryTree a -> b
inorder' _ a Leaf = a
inorder' f a (Node left val right) = inorder' f c right
    where b = inorder' f a left
          c = f b val
```

## Leaves with values

In that case the `BinaryTree` is defined like:

```
data BinaryTree a = Leaf a | Node (BinaryTree a) a (BinaryTree a)
```

In case the leaves have a value, we simply need to fix the first clause:

```
inorder' :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> BinaryTree a -> b
inorder' f b (Leaf a) = f b a
inorder' f a (Node left val right) = inorder' f c right
    where b = inorder' f a left
          c = f b val
```

Comment: `myTree` is a pattern that matches anything, not a constructor.

Comment: @amalloy: yeah, somehow i did not notice the lowercase, thanks.